# Join multiple features of same attribute name from a shapefile

Tags: arcpy, spatial-join

I have a shapefile of about 1300 species. In the shapefile some species has multiple features that makes about 3964 rows in the attribute table. I want to merge all features of a species into one using python code and the output will be a single shapefile of 1300 species with only 1300 rows (for example, all features of *Emoia adspersa* will merge into one). image of attribute table is attached herewith.

[image]

Comment: You have multiples shapefiles for some species or multiple polygons for some species in the same shapefile?

Comment: I have shapefiles of about 1300 speceis which are merged into one shapefile (lets say its name is X). The attached image is the attribute table of the X. In the image you see that species Emoia adspersa have six FID. I want to merge this into one. Some other species in X have multiple FID like Emoia adspersa. I want species with multiple FID will be merged into one for that species. So the resulted output should be a shapefile (lets say Y) of those 1300 species. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to use the [Dissolve tool](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/dissolve.htm), and make sure to choose a dissolve field (binomial), and choose to create mutlipart features.

You could run the following code in the Python window.

```
in_features = r"C:\yourInput.shp"
out_features = r"C:\yourOutput.shp"

arcpy.Dissolve_management(in_features, out_features, "binomial", multi_part=True)
```

Comment: Thank you so much dear Ianbroad! Your code works. This is so kind of you.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please accept the answer when you get a chance by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.